# Apache "No such file or directory" doesn't give me a file name

Tags: apache-2.2, php5, php

I'm using an Apache / Ubuntu config.

After installing `php-gd` library, I am getting error messages in my `/chroot/httpd/var/log/apache2/error.log` file (`/chroot/httpd/` being the "jail" in my chrooted environment) :

```
Error opening file for reading: No such file or directory
```

My problem is, this log doesn't mention the missing file name. Any idea how I could figure out who the culprit is ?

Pretty sure it's related to GD, probably some file I missed when copying to the chrooted part, but I don't know where to look for the missing file.

Thanks to anyone who has an idea.

Comment: You need to provide more details about how Apache is configured.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ldd` on your GD library files, you can see if all the required files where copied.

If `ldd`does not work, you can increase the verbosity of Apache logs. Putting `LogLevel debug` will suffice.

If even with a debug log you cannot find the problem, you can use `strace` on httpd process. Strace will show you all files opened.

```
strace -p <pid of httpd process> 2>&1 | grep ENOENT
```

You will have to know which `httpd` child will process your request, so it's good to change `StartServers` to 1 before trying this.

Comment: `ldd` was my first idea, but I couldn't find any missing files from there. Thanks for the LogLevel tip, tried that as well but it doesn't give any extra info: still just the generic "Error opening file for reading".
I'll try `strace`, and maybe re-double-check everything again.